Create mysql table from json string when 1st dimension hold columns and 2nd dimension holds rows
I am sitting with a legacy database and im trying to create this table in mysql using json strings stored in the database.
I have a table that stores a massive json string and one of the keys inside that json has a json string as follows:

data->"$.json" = {
  "col_a": [
    "a_1",
    "a_2",
    "a_3",
    "a_4"
  ],
  "col_b": [
    "b_1",
    "b_2",
    "b_3",
    "b_4"
  ],
  "col_c": [
    "c_1",
    "c_2",
    "c_3",
    "c_4"
  ]
}


and I need this output in mysql:

+-------+-------+-------+
| col_a | col_b | col_c |
+-------+-------+-------+
| a_1   | b_1   | c_1   |
| a_2   | b_2   | c_2   |
| a_3   | b_3   | c_3   |
| a_4   | b_4   | c_4   |
+-------+-------+-------+


So far I have managed to get the expected result by "indexing" multiple reads with ordinality and the joining on that index.

drop table if exists table1;
create table table1 (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  data json
);

insert into table1 (data) values (
  '{
    "other1":{
      "col_a": ["a_1", "a_2", "a_3", "a_4"],
      "col_b": ["b_1", "b_2", "b_3", "b_4"],
      "col_c": ["c_1", "c_2", "c_3", "c_4"]
    },
    "json": {
      "col_a": ["a_1", "a_2", "a_3", "a_4"],
      "col_b": ["b_1", "b_2", "b_3", "b_4"],
      "col_c": ["c_1", "c_2", "c_3", "c_4"]
    },
    "other2":{
      "col_a": ["a_1", "a_2", "a_3", "a_4"],
      "col_b": ["b_1", "b_2", "b_3", "b_4"],
      "col_c": ["c_1", "c_2", "c_3", "c_4"]
    }
  }'
);

select
  a.col_a,
  b.col_b,
  c.col_c
from
  table1 t
inner join
  json_table(
    t.data->'$.json',
    '$.col_a[*]'
    columns (
      row_id for ordinality,
      col_a varchar(10) path '$'
    )
  ) a
inner join
  json_table(
    t.data->'$.json',
    '$.col_b[*]'
    columns (
      row_id for ordinality,
      col_b varchar(10) path '$'
    )
  ) b
    on a.row_id = b.row_id
inner join
  json_table(
    t.data->'$.json',
    '$.col_c[*]'
    columns (
      row_id for ordinality,
      col_c varchar(10) path '$'
    )
  ) c
    on a.row_id = c.row_id;


But I am wondering if there isn't a more efficient way of doing it where I dont have to join each column manually.
Thanks in advance!

How does col_a in the JSON become col_1 in the output? And why does a_1 become 1_a?

You may parse using one JSON_TABLE, but the output will be unuseful. If you'd parse from '$.*[*]' then you'd obtain all values in one column. If you'd use multiple NESTED PATH then you'd receive rows with the value in one column and NULLs with another ones. See https://dbfiddle.uk/gmDd-TNs

@Barmar apologies, I used copilot to write the mockup data. And I was so tired I didnt realise. The question is fixed now.
